# PHP Installation broken - shows strange php code as response

Tags: apache2, php

I just wanted to open a very simple `index.php` which just contained

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

As a result I was seeing the following message in my browser:

```
handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I seems this message is shown if the local php installation is broken. For me this seems to have happend when I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.

The following commands resolved the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php
sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-php
```